# Who has access to our email address?

Tags: support, stackexchange, user-profile

Besides the database engineers in SE, who else has access to our email address? (I signed up using Google if it matters.)

How does stack overflow "protect" our email address?

Comment: (You can ask this on our meta, you don't need to go to another site just to ask questions about your experience on Programmers.SE)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

E-mail addresses on your profile are only visible to you, the Programmers.SE moderators, and the Stack Exchange team.

Other data that's shown on your profile but not visible to the public:

- Visited statistics
- OpenID
- Real Name
- Responses tab

Comment: Good to know. I got an email from someone asking me to help them with their code and I thought it was from SO!

Comment: @melee it might still be from SO: I once had someone contact me about their code; they went to my website (which is public, if you list it) and grabbed my contact information from there.